# Why isn't Xcode updating the remote references at every 10 minutes?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-fetch

From [Source Control Workflows in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/418/?time=1060)

> In Xcode Source Control Preferences, the Change bar can optionally be
> shown to show coworker's changes as they push them.
>
> This makes it easy to tell what part of a file is out of date.
>
> The changes are fetched from the server at a 10-minute interval.

When you have ‘Fetch and refresh status automatically’ shouldn’t these settings make Xcode pull down changes automatically for my remote branches? i.e. shouldn’t `origin/main` should get periodically updated at every 10 minutes?

It’s not happening for me. Last commit I have is for 5 days ago, but the server has a commit for today. Is this feature broken or do I need to do something else?

The Xcode docs for “Fetch and refresh server status automatically” are as:

> For remote repositories, periodically refresh the status of files that are updated on the server. (To manually refresh the status, choose Source Control > Fetch and Refresh Status.)

[image]